# my VPCis out of ips, how can I connect my EKS cluster to new VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

My VPC is out of IPs and we need more IPs. how Can I connect my **EKS** cluster to new VPC?

Comment: Please Edit your question and provide details of the IP ranges used in your VPC. It is possible to add additional CIDRs to subnets, but the VPC must have the space available. Are you sure that you have allocated all VPC addresses to the Subnets? If you're not sure, please show us the CIDRs for your VPC and all Subnets.